# Where do I install the Juju client?

Tags: juju, maas

I have a newbie question about juju.

Where should I install it ? In the MAAS server, in one of nodes or in the ubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 1):

You install Juju on your machine, the client. If you follow the instructions here you should be ready to go https://jujucharms.com/docs/#introduction